# ASP.NET MVC 3, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-3

First I'll show you what I do, and that there is. My project in ASP.NET MVC 3.

This is model for table Business.

```
[Table("Business")]
public class Business
{
    [Key]
    public long? BusinessId { get; set; }

    public Int32 LegalTypeId { get; set; }
    public Int16 BusinessTypeId { get; set; }
    public Int64 OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Int32 MainIndustryFieldId { get; set; }
    public String NameNative { get; set; }
    public String NameEnglish { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Logo { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }//It is Forign key with user table
}

[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }

    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String LoweredEmail { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public String PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
    public String PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsLocked { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Business Bussines { get; set; }
}
```

when I want to add information:

```
user.Business = new Business
{
    OwnerId = user.UserId,
    LegalTypeId = business.LegalTypeId,
    BusinessTypeId = business.BusinessTypeId,
    MainIndustryFieldId = business.MainIndustryFieldId,
    NameNative = business.NameNative,
    NameEnglish = business.NameEnglish,
    Logo = business.Logo,
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
};
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Business'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

In database column identity specification business chose is `Identity Yes`.

Somebody can tell what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure that in your EDMX model, your `BusinessId` is set to be handled by the database (property `StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity`)?? Also: **why** is your primary key nullable (`long?`) - makes no sense whatsoever. Your primary key **must never** be null !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`BusinessId` can not be empty/null since you have not specified that it should be autogenerated by Sql Server (which `Identity` means).

Since you are using Code First to generate your database, just change to:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public long? BusinessId { get; set; }
```

Comment: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'BusinessId'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035834/cant-insert-data-to-with-ef-with-master-detail-relationship

Answer (score 0):

override OnModelCreating in DbContext and add in it following  Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Business>().HasRequired(m => m.Address).WithRequiredPrincipal(m => m.Business).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```